# Why can't combine the two regular expression as one with `|`?

Tags: python, regex

Why can't combine the two regular expressions as one with `|`?

```
re.findall(r"[a-z]+-[a-z]+", text, re.MULTILINE) 
re.findall(r"[a-z]{2,}", text, re.MULTILINE)
```

The combined one expression.

```
re.findall(r"[a-z]+-[a-z]+|[a-z]{2,}", text, re.MULTILINE)
```

I found that `r"[a-z]+-[a-z]+|[a-z]{2,}"` can't express either `r"[a-z]+-[a-z]+"` or `[a-z]{2,}` ?

@pkqxdd and other,the regular expression `([a-z]+-[a-z]+)|([a-z]{2,})` do not equal to 
`[a-z]+-[a-z]+` or `[a-z]{2,}` ,here is my proof.
Please install  `textrac` and prepare a sample pdf file to test with.

```
import textract, re
text = textract.process("sample.pdf").decode() 
text = text.lower()
totalWords1 = re.findall(r"[a-z]+-[a-z]+", text, re.MULTILINE) 
totalWords2 = re.findall(r"[a-z]{2,}", text, re.MULTILINE) 
totalWords = totalWords1 + totalWords2
totalWords3 = re.findall(r"([a-z]+-[a-z]+)|([a-z]{2,})", text, re.MULTILINE) 
totalWords4 = re.findall("([a-z]+-[a-z]+)|([a-z]{2,})", text, re.MULTILINE)     
len(totalWords)
len(totalWords3)
len(totalWords4)
```

Show my experiment here.

```
>>> len(totalWords)
243322
>>> len(totalWords3)
240397
>>> len(totalWords4)
240397
```

[image]

Comment: regex101.com? did you test it? what is your data? what is supposed to be regexxed?

Comment: These patterns overlap and can match at the same locations in the string, so you won't be able to get the same matches like this.

Comment: It should be able to. What string makes you think otherwise?

Comment: In fact your error is not even within the regex itself but here: totalWords = ttalWords1 + totalWords2. You try to sum two overlapping sets. And yes, if you apply an expression with "or" it is not the same as applying the two subexpression separately. Your count cold match if the the sub expressions dusting have overlaps. For example , **aa-aa** will be matched by both subexpressions. The combined regex is greedy, and will try its best to match first part, and only if it falls will match the second

Comment: I fix the typo and retest , same conclusion.

Answer (score -2):

You probably need to group them, otherwise your `|` is only working on `[a-z]+` and `[a-z]{2,}`, which, as other people pointed out, overlap.

```
([a-z]+-[a-z]+)|([a-z]{2,})
```

This should do the trick.